# Sending a MVC project to someone

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The company I've applied for internship wanted me to do some mvc project. I've finished the project but I really don't know how to send it to them via email.The project includes a small database. I know I can't compress the solution folder and send it. Do I have to upload the project to a hosting service? If I deploy it to a hosting service and send them a website url then can they evaluate my work?

Comment: Just remove any compiled binaries, zip it up and send it to them.

Comment: Where do you see me making such a claim?

Comment: You should never include the database file. The person you give it to can generate their own database.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that you

- Register on Github or Bitbucket (if you want private repos)
- Create a Git repo with [this](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) .gitignore file.

Give them an url to a repo, and they will have a better impression of you.

Comment: Git is version control. Github and Bitbucket are two main companies that provide online Git hosting. Just like with SVN, TFS, etc. you upload your source code, so yes, someone else can then pull the source and work with the project just as you can.

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate script for your DB (You can generate with data too.)
2. Remove bin directory.
3. Add readme.txt file in which mention all steps that need to be performed for setting up your project.
4. Create zip file and send it.